# Calculate CPU usage from ticks

Tags: cpu-usage

How can CPU usage be calculated in % when I know the number of CPU ticks spent in: user, nice, sys, idle, and irq? For example the output of tick values is like this:

449760
3590
282250
298612690
0

but I want to know their percentage value. Is there some formula for this calculation?

Comment: %a1 = a1/(a1+a2+...+an) * 100

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan: This was the first thing which came to my mind, but that's not the correct way how it should be calculated.

Comment: What is your goal with this? Maybe there is some other way to find out (`time(1)` springs to mind)

Comment: The unix command  `time`, not to be confused with the posix call `time` which does something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your program can't know that because it simply doesn't know when it's not running. And when it IS running, it simply uses 100% of the CPU. In this case, precentages make sense only as relative measurements, but you haven't specified relative to WHAT.

Comment: It's not about program, those tick values are gathered from system.